# firefox 8 seemingly ignores preload="none" on video tag

Tags: html, video, preload

I have a new HTML5 site going live soon. One page has a carouse of 5 video tag (each with preload="none") which works great in chrome.

Just tested with firefox/firebug and the page takes ages to finish loading as it it downloading the whole 50meg videos behind the scenes. Why is it ignoring the preload attribute?

A.

Comment: It should be supported. Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804129/how-to-prevent-html5-audio-from-predownload-streaming-on-load

Answer (score 1):

The `preload` attribute is only a suggestion to the browser as to what you want it to do. That said, Firefox doesn't ignore it, so your problem is strange.

Do you have a sample online for us to look at? Or can you even post the code?

Comment: apologies, i restarted firefox and it seemed to fix it. Must have been a wierd firefox temp issue locally :/