# How to prevent HTML5 audio from predownload / streaming on load?

Tags: performance, html, audio, audio-streaming

I have a single page website which lists a collection of HTML5 audio players. The problem is the site has become slow because the following browsers start predownloading the content (mp3 and ogg)

```
Internet Explorer
Google Chrome
Firefox
Safari
(probably Opera)
```

I use the basic code to implement the players. Is there a way I can prevent the browsers from predownloading the audio files and only work when they click play?

```
<audio controls="controls" height="32" width="300" tabindex="0">
<source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://cdn.com/track.mp3"></source>
<source type="audio/ogg" src="http://cdn.com/track.ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

Comment: I think also the height and width are spat out by the browser so by default you can leave it empty, just `<audio controls="controls"` and `preload="none"` like M1th wrote below. As these are just browser rendered.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="none">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Note - `preload="none"` - can be used with VIDEO HTML5 and AUDIO HTML5.

The preload attribute is supported in all major browsers, except Internet Explorer and Opera.

Comment: Thank you. So this stops the HTML5 elements from auto downloading and preloading automatically. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

MSIE still accounts for some 30% of all web traffic, so `preload="none"` is only a part solution.  In a few pages where I had this problem, I add a small script to my page headers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addAudio(t) {
  var l=t.innerHTML.length;
  var audioName=t.parentElement.id;
  if( t.children.length==0) {
    t.innerHTML=t.innerHTML+'&nbsp; &nbsp; <audio controls="controls"><source src="'+
      audioName+'.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><source src="'+
      audioName+'.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /> No audio tag support</audio>';
  }
}
</script>
```

and then use DHMTL to dynamically add the audio tag, for example:

```
<li id="2_Lesson_1_Hello"><span onclick="addAudio(this)">Γεια σας</span></li>
```

What this does is to define a list item containing a text span.  When the person browsing clicks on the spanned text, the javascript fires and appends the `<audio>` tag.  You could alternatively use the `onmouseover` attribute so that the audio tag is added on hover.

Add the `preload` attribute to the generated code if you wish.  This is the simple approach, but if you are already using **jQuery** on your webpage, I note that this offers elegant alternatives.

Comment: Can you please either post the jQuery alternative and fully explain the code and what it is you mean? +1 for the effort, this put me off `Γεια σας` what is this code doing etc?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Sorry, I just pulled a line from one of my pages "Γεια σας" is just some character data in this example ( it's Greek for "hello"), just like "Your browser does not support..." is in yours.  The jQuery example is a different Q&A, and not really something that I want to cover here.  It's just that I regard this as advanced use of javascript and not really appropriate in your case if you need explanation of this simple action routine.